# Are weekly CAD/USD options untradeable?

Tags: options, foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar, cad-canadian-dollar

As below, cmegroup.com seems to indicate that [CADUSD weekly options (expiring 25 Mar 2011)](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/canadian-dollar_quotes_globex_options.html?exchange=XCME&foi=OPT&venue=G&productCd=6CM1&underlyingContract=6C&floorContractCd=CDM1&expMonth=201106#prodType=EV1) have absolutely no volume or pricing.

Does this mean they're impossible to trade? Or, if I had a broker, 
could I see bid and ask prices (even if no one actually got around to 
trading any contracts)?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the broker *would* be willing to show you bid/ask prices if you go to the trading interface, even before you make the actual transaction.

Comment: Got it... but you're saying that CME won't show bid/ask?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no volume, there's no market. If there's no market, you can't trade.

As fennec notes in a comment below, you may be able to see bid/ask prices on the trading interface: there *may* be people willing to trade at a certain price.

But if the potential market is so thin that there is no volume showing up, I still think that there's effectively no market. You could get stuck with a security that you can't unload if you want to, assuming you don't actually plan to exercise.

Comment: No volume doesn't necessarily mean nobody's willing to trade. There may be many people willing to buy or sell the options in question, at a certain price. They just haven't actually gone and traded the options - perhaps because nobody actually liked the prices anyone else was offering. This screen only shows the "last" price, not the bid / ask prices: the best prices anyone is willing to pay to buy it from you (what they bid for it) or sell it to you (what they're asking for it).

Comment: @fennec - True. I suppose if he could see bid/ask, there may be potential traders.

Answer (score 0):

You have the TYPE set for "Weekly Volatility Options (European)".  Are you sure that is what you want?.  If you set it to "Weekly Options" it looks a bit better, meaning that the volume is still 0, but there are prior settlements listed, which suggests that you could probably put in a market order and still be filled, but not at a price you like.

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't my screen shot above also have "settle" prices? I think Volatility just means the settle prices are quoted as implied volatilitys not in dollars

Comment: I'm assuming the settle price is for the CAD/USD future.  All of the options couldn't possibly have the same price.  It also says "Prior".  That means the price is stale and could have been from last week

Comment: The CAD/USD future was closer to 1.03 or something at the time. I'm pretty sure that's the settled volatility for these options. I agree it's rare for option volatilitys to be constant across strike prices (ie, volatility smile), but not totally unreasonable if they're using a "settle" price.